# I am creating a discord bot and this happened

Tags: javascript, discord

This is the code I have a problem with on bot.js:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'r!play luigi nutting') {
   const channel = Yee.channels.cache.get('general');
   channel.send('r!skip');
  }
});
```

Command prompt says this:

```
ReferenceError: general is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Discord Bot1\bot.js:59:20)
at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Discord 
Bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Discord 
Bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Discord 
Bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Discord 
Bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Discord Bot1\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Discord Bot1\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)``
```

(for context I created this bot because someone was spamming something in rythym but I didn't want to ban them)

Comment: Looks like you are showing some irrelevant code. Show us the lines around 59 in your bot.js, and please point the specific line 59.

Comment: I am a noob and can't identify parts of the code, so here is the full thing:

    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    const auth = require('./auth.json');

    client.on('ready', () => {
      console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    });
    client.on('message', msg => {
      if (msg.content === 'r!play luigi nutting') {
       const channel = Yee.channels.cache.get('general');
       channel.send('r!skip');
      }
    });
    

    client.on('ready', () => {

Comment: The rest didn't fit so here is the last part:

    
    client.user.setActivity("Minecraft")

   
})

    client.login("NjkzMzEzOTgyOTc4ODUwODc4.Xn9hwA.vk- 
   CXUDeBzBkxxAcoTVw37Wycss")

There are a couple of other things but I checked and they weren't part of the problem.

Comment: Edit the original question with the code.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Edit your question, put the code you posted in the comments there and delete the comments. It's hard to help you reading unformated code.

Comment: I put it in this -----> https://hastebin.com/wazemamexu.coffeescript

Comment: Everytime in programming that you receive an error, it will point you the file and line (sometimes column too) that the error occurs. In your case the error says: `C:\Discord Bot1\bot.js:59:20` so the first place that you will look for an error is on line 59 of that file. Post that line (use an comment to point us that line, people won't count lines manually im a StackOverflow question to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the error is here: const channel = `Yee.channels.cache.get('general');`

You need to specify the client, in this case it's already "client" as you defined it at the top: `const client = new Discord.Client();`.
So to get a channel with an id: `client.channels.get("ChannelID");`
And to get a channel with a name:

```
client.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "General");
```

Comment: Thank you. Had you not told me this I wouldn't have known.

Comment: I I tried running the bot again and got this: https://hastebin.com/redibutayu.css
It might be different than what I started with and if it is I don't know why

Comment: Did you remove the line where there is the Yee? The error came from there.

Comment: I don't think I did.

Comment: atually I think I fixed it